KotlinDL save and load model
I have this Neural Network:
class ValueNetwork(inputShape: Int, actionSpaceSize: Int) {
    private val model: Sequential

    init {
        model = Sequential.of(
            Input(inputShape.toLong()),
            Dense(128, Activations.Relu),
            Dense(128, Activations.Relu),
            Dense(1, Activations.Linear),
        )
        model.use {
            it.compile(
                optimizer = Adam(),
                loss = Losses.MSE,
                metric = Metrics.MAE
            )
        }
    }

    fun predictValue(state: State): Float {
    }

    fun update(trajectories: List<Trajectory>, discountedReturns: List<Float>, learningRate: Float) {
        model.use {
            it.compile(optimizer = Adam(learningRate), loss = Losses.MSE, metric = Metrics.MAE)
            it.fit(dataset, epochs = 10, batchSize = 64)
        }
    }

    fun saveModel(filePath: String) {
    }

    fun loadModel(filePath: String) {
    }
}

How can I save this Network after it's been trained and how can I reload this trained Network after initialization?
I tried the save() and loadWeights() functions. The save function apparently saves the model as a .pb or .json (depending on the configuration) and the variables to a .txt. The loadWeights() functions seems to be the wrong function for the task, however I cannot find the counterpart to the save() function.
fun saveModel(filePath: String) {
    model.save(File(filePath), writingMode = WritingMode.OVERRIDE )
}

fun loadModel(filePath: String) {
    val file = File(filePath)
    if (file.exists()) {
        model.loadWeights(file)
    }
}

I want to use these functions in the learning process of a PPO algorithm:
fun train(maxIterations: Int, initialEnv: DiscreteSchedulingEnv) {
    val env = initialEnv.deepCopy()

    for (iteration in 1..maxIterations) {
        val trajectories = collectTrajectories(env)
        updatePolicyAndValueNetworks(trajectories)
        env.reset()
    }

    policyNetwork.saveModel(policyNetworkPath)
    valueNetwork.saveModel(valueNetworkPath)
}

fun getBestAction(env: DiscreteSchedulingEnv): Action {
    policyNetwork.loadModel(policyNetworkPath)
    valueNetwork.loadModel(valueNetworkPath)

    return policyNetwork.getBestAction(env.currentState).toActionMap()
}

